# linq - selecting elements not equal to something

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a collection of strings.
How do I select all the elements that don't contain a certain parameter value?

```
List<string> TheList = .....

var TheCleanList = (from s in TheList
                    where s != parameter
                    select s).ToList();
```

I was thinking about where s!= parameter but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's fine just like that... what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need a *new* list you don't need Linq for this - use [`Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)- this avoids having to create a new list:

If you want to remove all strings that are equal to `Parameter`:

```
TheList.RemoveAll(s => s == Parameter);
```

If you want to remove all strings that contain `Parameter` (not clear from your question):

```
TheList.RemoveAll(s => s.Contains(Parameter));
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean:

```
List<string> TheList = ..... 

var TheCleanList = (from s in TheList 
                    where !s.Contains(parameter)
                    select s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

```
var TheCleanList = (from s in TheList
                    where !s.Contains(parameter)
                    select s).ToList();
```

Or

```
var TheCleanList = TheList.Where(s => !s.Contains(parameter)).ToList();
```

String.Contains is case-sensitive. If you want a case-insensitve:

```
string lower = parameter.ToLower();
...
where s.ToLower().Contains(lower)
```

Comment: Only one suggestion, possibly mention string.contains like!=, == and etc is a case sensitive evaluation. As I’ve seen many including myself forget sometimes Linq isn't TSQL and its case sensitive.